# How to use Linux "watch" command with python script

Tags: python, ubuntu, unix, terminal, watch

I want to run a python script every 2 hours using the "watch" Linux command.

I choose watch because it can be output to the terminal, and it doesn't need any other files to be created (as I understand it, this is what `cron` requires)

I've tried the following commands, but the terminal just feezes when doing them:
`watch -n 7200 'python test.py'`, `watch -n 7200 'python test.py`

If anyone could give me a hint on how to achive this, that would be great. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try disabling output buffering by adding "-u" switch to your Python command: `python -u test.py`.

Comment: I've tried adding `-u` to both of my commands and the terminal still freezes. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: Why is "other files [being] created" a problem? Is it only a problem if those files are on disk, and not if they're on a tmpfs location such as under `/run`? (I'm thinking about systemd support for temporary/transient units; systemd timers are the modern replacement for cron -- far better than abusing `watch` for a task it was never designed for).

Comment: See in particular `systemd-run`, which is able to create both transient services _and_ transient timers; while units' logs first go to the journal, `journalctl -f` can spool them back to the terminal in realtime (with filters used to exclude logs that _aren't_ from the particular program you want to follow).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not totally against created other files, but I was hoping for a simple solution such as using `watch`, but if it isn't possible, I'm definitely open to using other methods